# Custom validation in Laravel 4 for two checkboxes

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

how could one make the following validation:

```
something like exclude_if:field,value
The field under validation cannot be present if the field "field" is equal to value.
```

I thought of doing a custom validation, but I am not sure how to pass the value of the other field into the custom validation class.

A real world example for this case would be if we have let's say two checkboxes A and B, and we want to make sure that if A is checked then B cannot be checked.

Anybody? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has this covered out of the body. Lets say you don't want `additional_field` to be required to be filled in if the `field` is greater than the value `100`.

Firstly - do your static rules that never change:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
    'name' => 'required',
    'field' => 'required|numeric',
));
```

Then you can validate a `sometimes` rule against the `field` rule:

```
$v->sometimes('additional_field', 'required, function($input)
{
    return $input->field > 100;
});
```

You can read more about [conditionally adding rules in the Laravel Docs here.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)